# Federated claims-based authentication and single sign-on

Tags: .net, security, azure, wif

I have a requirement to pass credentials from one Microsoft .NET Web Application to another via Single-Sign-On at the Browser. I was hoping to utilize Windows Azure (ACS) as my Secure Token Service along with a Facebook/Open Id as the Issuing Authority for the claim for authentication purposes only.

Does anyone know how I achieve 'Federated claims-based authentication and single sign-on' across different .NET Web Application?

Note the two different Web Application are hosted in different data centers (not the cloud), credentials need to flow via the browser, is this achievable via the claim and a cookie (if so how)?

Cheers

---

*Update
e.g. User logs into Application A via ACS, they then click a button on App A which redirects them to App B (partner/3rd party site)

FYI - I don't think I will have access to change Application B (Partner Site), Application A yes...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're describing here is a hybrid scenario that works perfectly with the Windows Azure Access Control Service. And it doesn't matter if your application is on-premise or in the cloud. Basically your applications will simply need to use ACS as identity provider (right click on your projects, add STS reference). Once you've done that, the following will be possible:

1. User browses to application1.com
2. Authentication is required. application1.com redirects to the ACS 'login page' (where you can choose an identity provider) or lists all available identity providers.
3. User chooses to use Windows Live
4. User is redirected to login.live.com where he can enter his email address + password. He chooses to save the password and stay connected.
5. User is redirected to ACS with some claims. ACS redirects again with some claims to application1.com
6. User is authenticated in application1.com and his claims are available in the application.
7. User connects to application2.com
8. Authentication is required. application2.com redirects to the ACS 'login page' (where you can choose an identity provider) or lists all available identity providers.
9. User chooses to use Windows Live
10. **User was already authenticated in Windows Live before! And login.live.com redirects him immediately to ACS with some claims**
11. ACS redirects again with some claims to application2.com
12. User is authenticated in application2.com and his claims are available in the application.

Hope this helps.

Sandrino

Comment: Thanks for the help Sandrino, your number 8 requires Auth and number 9 then choose Windows Live ID (manual clicking the user, like Stackoverflow!), is it possible that they go from 6 to 7 from one Web Site to another and the claim passes which is seamless to the user e.g. they don't need to authenticate again (even clicking a button)? Thnx!

Comment: Thanks Andrew, I was going to customize the login page, I like it! I just updated my original post, I don't think I will have access to Application B (it's a partner site, we can't change it, as far as I know), is this still possible? ACS from Application A, creds (claims) flow to App B which is a 3rd party site with no login at Application B once authenticated at Application A? Thnx